# Using PHP to write to .swf files

Tags: php, flash

I was wondering how to basically edit a .swf file using php, to change a single variable or to change more. How would I go about doing this? Is there a way to edit it without knowing machine code?

If there is an example of how to do this, where can I find it?

Thanks!

Or, if there is an easier way to go about doing this, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is old, but since it happens to coincide with what I've been working on, I figured I would put something together in case others find it useful. The solution works for AS3 only. It let you to change the values of instance variables and constants.

Suppose you have the following class:

```
package pl.krakow.rynek {
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Advertisement extends Sprite {

        private var title:String = 'Euro 2012 LIVE!';

        /* ... */
    }
}
```

You want the var *title* to be something else. The code for doing so is as follow:

```
<?php

require_once 'flaczki/classes.php';

// parse the SWF file, decoding only those tags needed by the injector
$input = fopen("input.swf", "rb");
$parser = new SWFParser;
$injector = new AS3ConstantInjector;
$swfFile = $parser->parse($input, $injector->getRequiredTags());

$classConstants = array(
    'pl.krakow.rynek.Advertisement' => array(
        'title' => 'Free Beer!'
    )
);

// inject the values and reassemble the file
$injector->inject($swfFile, $classConstants);
$output = fopen($outPath, "wb");
$assembler = new SWFAssembler;
$assembler->assemble("output.swf", $swfFile);

?>
```

The code should be self-explanatory. The SWF file is first parsed, modifications are made, and the in-memory structure is saved to file. AS3ConstantInjector.inject() expects as the second argument an array of arrays keyed by the qualified names of the classes you wish to modify. The arrays themselves hold the new values for each class, with the key as the variable/constant name.

To see The variables in a SWF file, use AS3ConstantExtractor:

```
<?php

require_once 'flaczki/classes.php';

$input = fopen("button.swf", "rb");
$parser = new SWFParser;
$extractor = new AS3ConstantExtractor;
$swfFile = $parser->parse($input, $extractor->getRequiredTags());
$classConstants = $extractor->extract($swfFile);

print_r($classConstants);

?>
```

The Flaczki classes can be downloaded at http://code.google.com/p/flaczki/downloads/list

You can find out more about the Flaczki framework at the project development blog at http://flaczkojad.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 4):

take a look at libming

php documentation at http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.ming.php

Comment: Does data written with libming to the flash file stay with it?

Answer (score 2):

With Actionscript, it's very simple to load external data: [XML](http://www.kirupa.com/web/xml/XMLwithFlash3.htm) and [JSON](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/516/1/JSON-Communication-with-Flash-Loading-Data/Page1.html) are two standardized ways to do it, and both are easily generated by PHP. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to make it possible to download a copy of a flash file, but have that flash file be custom to the user who downloaded it. (i.e., they made a flash logo, and they can now download the .swf)

Comment: @cyclone: owkay i see... this way, generating is idd the only option... marby include this in the question.

Answer (score 1):

check out the [SWF-library](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.swf.php) in php

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking how to generate swf files, do the opposite and let the internal behavior depend on external logic in a php script. This way you never need to (re)compile your swf.